# What is a third party cookie?

Tags: cookies, facebook

What is a third party cookie and how is it used in Facebook connect feature?

Answer (score 4):

A third-party cookie is a cookie from domain **A**, being set in domain **B** (while visitor is in domain **B**).

as you may know, a cookie is a file that is set on a per-domain basis only, and cannot be shared across different domains, so, how can it be that domain **A** has set a cookie while being in domain **B**? 
these third-party cookies are set while retrieving components from other domains than the current one being viewed, and the cookies are set via HTTP response headers `Set-Cookie`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: name=value

(content of page)
```

More information:

[What are third-party cookies](http://o.bulport.com/index.php?item=55#thpcth)

[Third party cookies](http://www.bobulous.org.uk/misc/third-party-cookies.html)

[Setting a cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie)